# AngularJS + Sailsjs + Nginx = incorrect date from UTC

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, nginx, sails.js

I'm saving a date in a mysql db as datetime using UTC, so if cst time is 2014-07-22 10:34 am in the db it will save as 2014-07-22 15:34. When testing the app locally, osx 10.9, with either local db or connecting to remote db angular formats it correctly as 2014-07-22 10:34 am. When running the app on a server, ubuntu + nginx + sailsjs, the date reads as 2014-07-22 3:34 pm, so it's not taking into account the timezone. On the server I've set the correct timezone using tzconfig, and it shows local as cst and universal as utc. As I mentioned above, I can connect the local sails app to use the remote database and the time gets formatted correctly. So as long as the sails server is running locally the time is formatted correctly, but if I use the sails app on the server the time is incorrect. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs a better explanation. It is hard to tell when exactly the date is messing up. Are you saying that when the sails server is moved to a remote server the date is wrong?

I know personally I stopped using date/time formats and make everything a unix timestamp (ie a NUMBER). This is universal and is never translated till I want it to be translated.

I use this in connection with moment.js (on the server and in angular) to translate my times to/from number and in the correct timezone.

This method has helped tremendously because dates can be manipulated by the server, the db or the client or the db adapter. Maybe none, maybe all and it might event be poor design on my part, but after switching to numbers, I never had these problems ever again.